# rbenv clobbering my gem INSTALLATION DIRECTORY when using system

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv

I want to use rbenv for setting ruby versions on a project per project basis. Otherwise, I want to use my default system ruby setup for everything else.

The problem I am having is the even though `rbenv version` returns `system`, `gem` command still uses the rbenv shim (`.rbenv/shims/gem`). So when I do `gem environment` my INSTALLATION DIRECTORY is `'/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8'`. I would rather it remains `~/.gem/`. I can see it still is that when I run `/usr/bin/gem enviroment`. I can't figure out where the rbenv shim gem is getting its settings from.

I've tried modifying my GEM_HOME both in my shell, and changing it in `~/.gemrc` but that has no effect. I've been searching around with no luck. Hopefully someone here can help. Just some pointers to where the rbenv gem shim is pulling its values from would be helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Since rbenv shims are pretty high in your PATH, their purpose is to intercept any invocation of `ruby`, `gem`, and similar, even if the currently selected Ruby version is "system". You shouldn't be worried about that.

Now, the default installation path for your system Ruby will always be `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8`. Here's my `RBENV_VERSION=system gem env`:

```
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/mislav/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

However, if you **don't** use `sudo` (and you shouldn't), `gem install` won't have write access to that directory, and will install the gems in the next writeable path, which is `~/.gem/ruby/1.8`. That seems to be the behavior you want.

Comment: thanks mislav. For some reason, i'm not seeing it fallback to the writeable path. :/ It seems to try to only install to the INSTALLATION DIRECTORY - it doesn't seem to use GEM PATHS for installation.

Comment: What behavior do you see when you don't use sudo? Is `~/.gem/ruby/1.8` writeable by your user? If it doesn't exist, are its parent directories executable+writeable by your user?

Comment: yes, all writeable by my user. When using /usr/bin/gem, everything works fine. its only through the rbenv shim where its not behaving as i would like.

Comment: Running `gem` through rbenv should be identical to running `/usr/bin/gem` (check with `rbenv which gem`).

Comment: thats what I thought. And rbenv which gem does indeed show /usr/bin/gem . So I'm at a loss why config reported by gem env (which uses the rbenv shim) is different from /usr/bin/gem env. You can see the outputs here: https://gist.github.com/meeech/f0d4393bb6d0b9f54c30

Comment: Any rbenv plugins that might be setting GEM_HOME/GEM_PATH? A lot of them affect that

Comment: Not that I can see. The only one is bundler, but I've turned it off (and rbenv rehash) but results are still the same.

Comment: Which plugins do you have? How did you "disable" the rbenv-bundler plugin? (That plugin is evil and you shouldn't use it.)

Comment: I disabled it with `rbenv bundler off` is there a way to wipe it from rbenv (or should i just trash the folder)

Comment: I don't know if there's an uninstall script. You should ensure it's gone from `plugins` directory, that `rbenv hooks rehash` doesn't list its script, and you can nuke rbenv `shims` directory just in case and then `rbenv rehash`.